# VBA: Modify via code where the data labels appear on a chart

Tags: excel, vba

How could I, via code, make the data labels appear below for a specific trend line [Orange line in the picture] on a chart. See below pictures for more understanding. I had to manually do this right now... right click on the data points and choose "below" for displaying data labels.

What I have:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: You didn't try the macro recorder when you did this manually? I would assume that would be helpful.

Comment: Right. I should really start to understand how to use that macro recorder. I will check and report. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the macro recorder, this is what it printed and this is what worked!

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Select
Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
```

Comment: Redacting some of my questions because I received a ban on new questions due to negative voting. I don't understand what I could do to get this ban lifted. IMO, the questions that I have asked were clearly stated with a problem statement and with what I am looking for. For example, I can't fathom why the above question received a down vote. I am new to Excel and have not used a macro recorder before. Someone pointed me in the direction and I learnt how to use it. I fixed the problem and provided an answer for anyone interested. I don't know what else I could do to improve this question!